# How Can we show One Key and its Values from Map<String, List<Object>> at a time on a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, for-loop, collections

I am making a Quiz Project in which I want show One Question and it's respective options at a time. I have created a DB and by using HQL I have brought that data on to the JSP page. I have put that data in 
MAP. I am iterating the map using entrySet. Right now I am able to show all Questions and it's Options on a JSP page, but I want to show one question and it's options at a time and on clicking of a NEXT button I want to show the next Question and it's options and so on.

My Code On Jsp Page is:

```
<%
Map<String, List<Answers>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Answers>>();
map = (Map)session.getAttribute("questAndAns");

%>  

<%
for(Map.Entry<String,List<Answers>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
%>
<br>
<%
List list =  entry.getValue(); 
if(list != null && list.size() > 0)
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++)
{
 Answers answers =(Answers) list.get(i);
%>
<%= answers.getAnswer() %>
```

String in Map contains a question and List  are the options of that particular Question.
How can I achieve it?

Help Appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map.keySet()` to get all the questions. Then use `map.get(key)` to get list of options for it.

```
Set<String> questions = map.keyset();
for(String q : questions) {
    List<Answers> answers = map.get(q);
    . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should encapsulate each question along with its possible answers in a dedicated object, using a class like this:

```
public class Question {
    private String text;
    private List<String> options;
    // getters and setters ...
}
```

Then you can store your `Question` objects in a `List<Question>` or a `Map<String,Question>` so that each has an identifier (numeric or string). When a page is loaded, you can retrieve the `Question` with a given identifier (either passed as a request parameter or given by some other logic) and pass it as a page/request attribute.

I hope I understood the problem and this helps.

On a side note, consider using [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) and [JSTL tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) rather than plain Java code in JSPs.